# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "" Array

Tags: java, exception

I cant find any problems in my program.  Every time the user inputs a number, I want it to save it on the array A, but when the user tries to type the second number, the `NumberFormatException` error appears.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:470)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:499)
at practice.test(end.java:22)
at end.main(end.java:7)
```

Here is the program:

```
import java.io.*;

class end {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        practice obj = new practice();
        obj.test();
    }
}

class practice {
    void test() throws IOException {
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        int A[] = new int[5];
        String x;
        int a, b, c, i = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println("Insert a number");
            x = br.readLine();
            A[i] = Integer.parseInt(x);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried printing out what `x` is?

Comment: Works okay for me...

Comment: this line makes sense `For input string: ""` you cant convert an empty string to an Integer

Comment: You could validate the input and skip any that is invalid, or you might use a `Scanner` and `hasNextInt()` with `nextInt()`.

Answer (score 0):

Code works absolutely fine, provided you enter only numbers. If you enter empty string, it will give you the error what you have posted.

Might need to `add a check for empty string`.

```
if(!x.isEmpty()){
               A[i] = Integer.parseInt(x);
            }

public class end {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        practice obj = new practice();
        obj.test();
    }
}

class practice {
    void test() throws IOException {
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        int A[] = new int[5];
        String x;
        int a, b, c, i = 0;
        for (i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++) {
            System.out.println("Insert a number");
            x = br.readLine();
            A[i] = Integer.parseInt(x);
        }

        for (i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++) {
            System.out.println(A[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Insert a number
2
Insert a number
3
Insert a number
4
Insert a number
5
Insert a number
6
User input
2
3
4
5
6
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you try to input an empty String from your Stacktrace you should check if the input is empty or not...

```
 InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        int A[] = new int[5];
        String x;
        int a, b, c, i = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println("Insert a number");
            x = br.readLine();
            //check if input is empty
            if(!x.isEmpty()){
               A[i] = Integer.parseInt(x);
            }
        }
```